# Spread operator for strings

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, spread-syntax

I read about *spread syntax* on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) and that it can be used with both arrays and strings:

> Spread syntax allows an iterable such as an **array** expression or **string** to be expanded in places where zero or more arguments (for function calls) are expected - mdn.

It's clear for me with arrays. It will expand the elements as separate arguments.
But I didn't find examples for strings.

So, what are the rules to use spread syntax to expand a string in a function call?
Should the string characters be separated with spaces cause I tried this and it printed 3.

```js
var x = "1 2 3";
console.log(Math.max(...x));
```

Comment: Please be aware that MDN is **not** the JavaScript specification.

Comment: Why wouldn't it print 3, max operates on numbers so it is going to try to turn each passed value into a number and then do comparisons. If you want an example try: `console.log(..."test")` in the console you will see each letter placed separately

Comment: I'm really not sure why many of the current answers aren't directly answering the actual question: "What are the rules to use spread syntax to expand a string in a function call", but the spread operator will simply convert each character of the string into an argument, for example: `"1 2 3"` becomes `"1", " ", "2", " ", "3"`

Comment: Thanks very much @KhauriMcClai, this what I was looking for.

Comment: @KhauriMcClain isn't that exactly what i answered?

Comment: You touched on it a little @Olian04 but I think your answer could be more thorough.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As we can see below, your example is actually spreading to 5 elements, where 2 of them are space characters. You can also see below that the spread operator on a string seems to be the same as using `.split('')`.

```js
const x = "1 2 3";
console.log([...x]);

console.log(x.split(''));
```

Comment: Good answer, though in terms of function calls I'd say that `console.log.apply(null, x.split(""))` and `console.log(...x)` are equivalent. The example you currently has will in both cases log an array while using apply or the spread syntax will use each element of an array as a separate argument to a function. I.e. the difference between `console.log([a, b, c])` and `console.log(a, b, c)`

Comment: `[..."‍❤️‍"]` will create an array with 6 items, while `"‍❤️‍".split("")` will create one with 8

Comment: How do you know it spilts, any specs, or anything ?

Answer (score 5):

Math.max on an empty string evaluates on *empty string* like `+" "` or `Number(" ")` therefore `0`

```js
const str = "1 2 3";
console.log( Math.max(...str))  // ["1"," ","2"," ","3"] >>> [1,0,2,0,3] >>> 3
```

**It's not wise** to spread directly a string with numbers, cause `34 8 9` will max to `9`. Always **split** by your separator `num.split(/ +/)` (*one-or-more spaces*) beforehand:

```js
const str = "1 34 9 2";

// Issue:
console.log( Math.max(...str) )  // 9   since [1,0,3,4,0,9,0,2]

// Fix:
console.log( Math.max(...str.split(/ +/)) ) // 34
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var x = "123";
console.log(Math.max(...x));

// prints 3
```

`...` treats the string as an iterable, equivalent to an array with one character mapped to one element.

Answer (score 1):

Spread syntax will result in 5 elements, where 2 of them are space characters:

```js
const x = "1 2 3";
console.log([...x]);

//=> ["1", "", "2", "", "3"]
```

---

**In detail:**

The result of the spread operator will be `["1", "", "2", "", "3"]` containing the space characters.

Acting on this result, **Math.max()** will try and find the biggest number in the array, by converting non-Number types to Number, similar to running `Number("1")` to convert a `String` into a `Number`. The space characters are converted into a Number 0, similar to `Number("") === 0`.

So, you're left with the following list of numbers: `[ 1, 0, 2, 0, 3 ]` upon which **Math.max()** will pick 3 as the biggest number of all.

Comment: why, what you get by writing same things ?

Comment: Can you elaborate on that @YAN? I don't really understand the question.

Comment: I got it, I was basically asking how it works, now I understand it